# I want to concatenate an index in a for loop

Tags: javascript

I know very little about javascript, but I need to do the following to include in a PHP website that I have written, where the data has to be put in a pipe delimited string.
I have made a sample script which does the job..

```
var data_0="a";
var data_1="b";
var data_2="c";
var data_3="d";
var all="";
all = all + "|" + (data_0);
all = all + "|" + (data_1);
all = all + "|" + (data_2);
all = all + "|" + (data_3);
alert( all );
```

The problem is that there will be 50 or more data items.
I therefore want to use a for loop to do it, and I tried this which is clearly not right..

```
var data_0="a";
var data_1="b";
var data_2="c";
var data_3="d";
var all="";
for (var i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
{
all = all + "|" + (data_ + i);
}
alert( all );
```

Can someone explain how it should be done?

Comment: Use an array, and use [`Array.prototype.join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join). Having variables `data_X` is wrong in virtually all languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var data_0="a";
var data_1="b";
var data_2="c";
var data_3="d";
var all="";
for (var i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
{
all = all + "|" + eval("data_" + i);
}
alert( all );
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than multiple variables, you need a single `array`:

```
var data = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
```

To join all the elements of the array, use `.join()`.

```
var all = data.join(', ');
```

**Working Example:**

```js
var data = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
var all = data.join(', ');
console.log(all);
```

---

**N.B.** *Since you are more familiar with PHP than with javascript, these two lines in javascript:*

```
var data = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
var all = data.join(', ');
```

*are the equivalent of these two lines in PHP:*

```
$Data = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd');
$All = implode(', ', $Data);
```

Comment: The concat bit with the pipe will help me to make it more simple, but I wanted to know how to make the for loop work. It's the concat for the data and index that is causing it to fail. Seems like the first answer is it.

Comment: Yes, that's it. The eval bit was the way to do it. It was not possible to use an array anyway, for reasons that are not relevant to the problem.